# Should this question be un-deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I was presented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19195544) review in Triage.

[image: Question]

Question looks OK to me personally. It contains code, is on-topic, clear and answerable I guess.

Some voters voted to close it as off-topic. I do not understand why?

There are many down votes on the question as well. Looking at [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49428656/#comment85858856_49428656) comment, I opened the question in other tab and tried to get more context. While I was reading, OP added some rude comments. I guess he did the same earlier. Also, due to such a behavior, question got many down votes and finally got deleted while I was still reading it.

Rude comments is one issue that I understand attracted down votes. I do not understand why close votes?

Apart from that, down vote should be cast if post itself is bad. As I said earlier, the post looks good. But, votes are totally dependent on each user's thinking; so nothing could be much changed here.

Bad comments can be deleted and user may be punished with whatever (post ban?) rules Stack Overflow defined. But, if I understand correctly, question should remain open.

Please correct if I am wrong.

**Edit**

With [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364958/should-this-question-be-un-deleted?noredirect=1#comment567427_364958) comment, it looks that OP put rude text in question itself. I was not able to check the edits that time (question got deleted) and I do not have enough tools to see it now. But if that is the case, deleting the question is correct action.

Comment: When a comment speaks of vandalism and rudeness then you don't have to guess how this happened.

Comment: @HansPassant: I agree; and user should be punished for that. But my point is, post itself is good.

Comment: Can you add comment images for low-reps?

Comment: Not getting help with your problem is as basic a "punishment" as anyone can receive.  If you like the question then just ask it yourself.

Comment: @user202729: I am low-rep myself.

Comment: 'post itself is good' well, was the before, or after, the OP editied out all the code and replaced it with: 'fuck this site ........ fuck this site ........ fuck this site ........' ?

Comment: @MartinJames: Was that so? I do not know this. Question got deleted while I was still reading it and the comments. If OP put those words in question itself; then it should be deleted. I agree.

Comment: @AmitJoshi I'm afraid so.  I have to admit that I think the same sometimes, (usually after yet another super-duplicate:), but I don't actually post it!

Comment: Post itself isn't all that great either, IMO. (I mean, before the vandalism). I don't find it completely clear.

Comment: @MartinJames come on, don't blame the site for what individuals do.

Comment: @yivi I didn't really look at the code, was it not div centering, (again)?

Comment: The post complains about [the modal being pushed out of the view when view gets resized](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oqWmqb). Does the poster want the modal to be always smaller than the view? I guess so, but it's not immediately evident in my opinion.

Comment: _"Question looks OK to me personally. It contains code, is on-topic, clear and answerable I guess."_ That's not exactly a ringing endorsement. What is lost if we lose this post? What is gained if it's visible? Is this a clear and findable expression of the problem? Or is it just another grain of sand?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

What happened here was that the OP wasn't happy with how the community responded to their question, so they decided to edit the question to contain rather a few words conflicting with the "Be Nice" policy. I [rolled back that edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/49428656/4) and left them a comment explaining that it's bad to vandalise your own posts, and even worse to do that with rude words. Additionally, I told them they could delete their question if they wanted (it has no answers on it). As you can see in the screenshot the OP did so themselves. I see no reason to undelete a post without answers where the OP has willingly deleted their own post.

Comment: "I see no reason to undelete a post without answers where the OP has willingly deleted their own post." In particular, if you think that there's a useful question in there somewhere then *you can ask a new question yourself*.  There's no need to force someone with no interest in attempting to improve the question to have it attached to them if they don't want to.

Comment: Most of the details you mentioned in answer were not visible to me. It was so quick, I was not even able to read everything that time. Question got quickly deleted. With the details you mentioned here, un-deleting does not make sense.